# How to init view by kendo and angular?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Is there any option to init view for kendo ui with angular, something like in this code:

```
<div data-role="view" id="foo"><a data-role="button">Foo</a></div>

<div data-role="view" id="bar"><a data-role="button">Bar</a></div>

<script>
new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), { initial: "#foo" });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible via the `kendo-mobile-application` directive:

```
<body kendo-mobile-application="mobileApp" ng-app="foo">
  <kendo-mobile-view ng-controller="mine" k-title="'My Title'" k-layout="'default'">
    <kendo-mobile-header>
        <kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
            <kendo-view-title></kendo-view-title>
        </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
    </kendo-mobile-header>
  </kendo-mobile-view>

  <script>
    angular.module("foo", [ "kendo.directives" ])
        .controller("main", ["$rootScope", "$scope", function($rootScope, $scope) {
            $scope.hello = "Hello World!";

            // show the application loader animation
            $rootScope.mobileApp.showLoading();
        });
  </script>
</body>
```

More info is available in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/angular/angular).

Comment: Thanks for answer. But how could i initialize view with kendo&angular with if(something){load view 1}else{load view 2}

Comment: As i understand the initializing here on application level and not on view level. Is there initializing on view level?

Comment: Actualy, I can make it with routing like:angular.module('myApp').config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/view1', {
controller: 'Controller1',
templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html',
}).when('/view2', {
controller: 'Controller2',
templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html',
});
}); and set views in each html file

Comment: The above code doesn't work. There is a mistake with controller name. But when i copy this code into real html page it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't get this to work either.  I actually see a field named after my app name on $scope, not $rootScope, but it's undefined.  Would love to know how we are supposed to use the loading indicator with Angular but can't find any info on how to do that or how to reference the Kendo application instance in Telerik's documentation.